# Can't deploy next-sitemap on Vercel + Next js

Tags: next.js, sitemap, vercel

I would like to use next-sitemap to automatically generate and deploy a sitemap. However, I am getting a deploy error and this is not working.

*sitemap.config.js*
(root directory)

```
module.exports = {
  siteUrl: 'https://example.com',
  generateRobotsTxt: true,
  sitemapSize: 7000,
  outDir: './out',
};
```

*package.json*

```
...
    "build": "next build && next export && next-sitemap sitemap.config.js",
...
```

*error text*

```
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module '/vercel/path0/web/node_modules/next-sitemap/dist/esm/cli.js' imported from /vercel/path0/web/node_modules/next-sitemap/bin/next-sitemap.mjs
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
    at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:418:11)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:981:10)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1078:11)
    at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:530:30)
    at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:251:18)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:79:40)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:78:36) {
```

Comment: I would avoid using next-sitemap. It appears to be poorly maintained.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try with postbuild scripts ?

```
{
  ...
  "build": "next build",        
  "postbuild": "next-sitemap"
}
```